# Как получить перенаправление на страницу после post

Tags: c#, httpclient

Мне нужно после моего post запроса(авторизации например) получить перенапралвение на страницу, где уже я вошел под пользователем, как это можно реализовать на c#?
Я нашел такую вещь, но только для java
https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-redirect-on-http-post

Comment: Отправили запрос - получили данные. В данных либо ключ авторизации, с которым вы делаете GET запросы на сайт, либо все необходимое вам. В чем проблема у вас? P.S. Это случаем [не вы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100325/)? Уж прям подозрительно по одному направлению идете...

Comment: Нет, это вообще другая тематика вопроса

Comment: Не сказал бы, человек также хочет отправить POST и получить данные, использует даже ссылки, которые я встречал в ваших вопросах. Ну да ладно, проблема то в чем?

Comment: Ну может он смоих вопросов смотрел и взял, он как я понял html получить хочет, а мне нужна переадресация на другую страницу. Я отправляю post, получаю `{"result":{"Success":true}}`, я до сих пор пытаюсь нажать кнопку входа на авито. Я понимаю что там ссылка меняется, но возможно ли сделать так, чтобы он сам меня перенес туда, или выдал эту ссылку после post, в консоли

Comment: Прочитайте первый мой комментарий. Есть разные запросы и разные ответы, некоторые возвращают сразу данные, некоторые вспомогательную информацию, некоторые дают ключ доступа. Сайты обычно как работают: Вы зашли (GET) - Он отдал вам "заглушку", некую HTML страничку, которая содержит только места, куда будет подгружен контент и скрипты, которые этот контент подгружают (JS). Когда страница загружена, начинают работать те самые JS скрипты, они отправляют POST/GET запрос на некий адрес с некими параметрами - тот адрес возвращает необходимые данные ответом.

Comment: То есть там нет редиректа (у API) и если вам сервер выдал `{"result":{"Success":true}}`, то смотрите что он вам дополнительно с этим выдал (Cookie, может заголовок или еще что). Либо смотрите, что делает уже сам сайт, когда получает `true` от API.

Comment: Понял, спасибо, пороюсь тогда в заголовках, которые выдает